# Delete multiple rows using checkboxes in JSP

Tags: html, sql, jsp, servlets, checkbox

I'm new to coding and JSP language and i want to know how to delete multiple records in an HTML table using checkboxes, i manage to delete one single row, anyway here is my code and thanks in advance!

---

• An picture which explain what i want to do :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03jYl.png)

• Full JSP code :

```
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <style>
            th,tr,td
            {
                font-family: Lucida Sans;
            }
            th{
                background-color: aquamarine;
            }
            #btn{
                font-family: Lucida Grande;
                border-radius: 5px;
                font-size: 100%;
                width: 100px;
                height: 25px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <%!
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
        String user = "root";
        String pass = "1122";
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;



         public Connection getCon(){
             try{
                 Class.forName(driver);
                 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
             }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
             return conn;
         }
    %>

    <%
           String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_id = ?";
           PreparedStatement psDelete = null;


           String id = request.getParameter("ckbox");
           String clickDelete = request.getParameter("submit");

            try{
                psDelete = getCon().prepareStatement(deleteQuery);


                    psDelete.setString(1, id);


                if(clickDelete !=null){

                    psDelete.executeUpdate();


    %>   
    <body>
    <script>
            alert("Deleted successfully!");
    </script>
    <% }

            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }

    %>

    <%
        String fetchQuery = "SELECT * FROM persons ORDER BY person_id";
            try{
                stmt = getCon().createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(fetchQuery);

    %>

        <div align="center">

            <form name="myform" action="newjsp.jsp" method="POST">
 <table border="1" cellpadding="9" style="border-collapse: collapse">
   <tbody>
                <tr>
     <th>#</th>
     <th>Employee ID</th>
     <th>First Name</th>
     <th>Job</th>
                </tr>

    <%  while(rs.next()){
    %>

                <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox" value="<%= rs.getString("person_id") %>" /></td>
     <td><%= rs.getString("person_id")%> </td>
     <td> <%= rs.getString("first_name") %> </td>
     <td> <%= rs.getString("job_title") %> </td>
                </tr>

    <%          }
    %>
   </tbody>
  </table>
    <%
            }catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    %>
    <br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="submit" id="btn"/>
            </form>


        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

• The important part i guess :

```
<%
           String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM persons WHERE person_id = ?";
           PreparedStatement psDelete = null;


           String id = request.getParameter("ckbox");
           String clickDelete = request.getParameter("submit");

            try{
                psDelete = getCon().prepareStatement(deleteQuery);


                    psDelete.setString(1, id);

                    psDelete.executeUpdate();


    %>
```

```
            <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="ckbox" value="<%= rs.getString("person_id") %>" /></td>
 <td><%= rs.getString("person_id")%> </td>
 <td> <%= rs.getString("first_name") %> </td>
 <td> <%= rs.getString("job_title") %> </td>
            </tr>

<%          }
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have some advice for you. Don't use scriptlets. They are deprecated due to their lack of reusability and security issues.
Luckily, there are alternatives to that. You can use JSTL library to insert java code or expression language (`${...}`) to insert a value of an attribute.
The problem with your code is at the while loop. A while loop in jsp's just doesn't work. You can try using JSTL `for` tags to iterate through all the elements of the result set and create all the checkboxes.
Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Hello sir, thank you for your comment. About what you said, it doesn't matter since i'm forced to study this just to pass an exam by the end of the year, maybe i can do that in my personal projects, cause i've always believed our educational system is really bad :^)

Comment: Thank you sir! I know how it's working just to pass an exam. You probably wont use pure jsp anyway in your projects. You'll use some framework (Struts or Spring). Good luck!